# Flot charts doctype issues

Tags: doctype, flot

I've got a Flot chart issue. When I use the recommended DOCTYPE, the chart does not display. But if I remove the DOCTYPE it shows up perfectly.

I am using excanvas.js. Here's the DOCTYPE I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I have tried numerous other DOCTYPES, but to no avail.

Am I not using excanvas.js properly? I am calling it along with everything else:

```
<script src="../flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="../flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="../flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<link href="../flot/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Thanks, all!

Comment: What are the errors in firebug?

Comment: Update: Here's what I've got in the Firebug errors panel: Error#1: 
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

<!DOCTYPE html>

excanvas.min.js (line 4)

Error#2: TypeError: jQuery("div.wp-tabs").wptabs is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

jQuery('div.wp-tabs').wptabs();

wp-ui-...r=0.8.5 (line 1136)

Error #3:
uncaught exception: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 950, height = 0

Comment: I think that last error - uncaught exception height = 0 may be my issue?

Comment: Does your flot target div not have a height?

Comment: Fixed! It did have a height, but was in percentage format for  flot.resize.js. I went ahead and gave it a fixed height and width in px and used the style max-width attribute to get the job done. Thanks! Just needed a new set of eyes on this.